# How does a unix binary decide where to get a shared library?

Tags: shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04, vlc-media-player

I use a Linux executable, the libraries are located in many place. I mean the same library with different version. The problem is the executable picks up the executable in wrong library. The OS is Ubuntu 64 bit.

The libraries are located /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. I would like that it would use /usr/local/lib version.

To force it to use the /usr/local/lib version.  I copied the .so from there to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and deleted .so referenced there.
The result was that the software (VLC) did not use the newly copied libraries but it stopped working properly and it did not find the library at all. Despite of the fact, it was over there.
So it is not clear how VLC decides what library to use.

It is clear that it uses the files under /etc/ld.so.conf.d to get the library paths. (Files contain /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
WHy does not it choose the library I copied under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu or under /usr/local/lib ?

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.

Update:

I thought I could just add another version , the program would use that but it seems that the version of the library is set at compile time for the given executable. so it will not use the new version, just because I delete an old one.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set. <- that is your problem

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: because that is where libraries are searched for.

Comment: Aren't those things set when the program is compiled and linked? Please provide more details including specific errors and the library in question.

Comment: yes, I thought I could just add another version , the program would use that but it seems that the version of the library is set at compile time. so it will not use the new version, just because I delete an old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways this can be achieved

a) Setting `rpath` at linktime - this is a very ugly and unportable way and should be avoided whereever possible

b) Using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (don't forget to export that if you change it!)

---

If you want to use a specific version/modified/foo-reason for your binary I suggest to

a) link against it statically if the license allows that

b) use `LD_PRELOAD` like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

c) modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (make sure your path is the **very first** in that list, they are searched in order) by using a run-script which does that